# Comments on the sequence diagram I created

Tags: sequence-diagram, staruml

Here is the explanation about this sequence diagram. A user enters their credentials and login to the system. The Login Servlet will be the controller and communicate with the Webservice to retrieve the data and checked whether credentials are valid.

Then if successful, the loginservlet redirects to GetMember Servlet which is the controller to communicate to the webservice and display the member profile details for update. After the user has entered their details and clicked on submit, the MemberEditProfile Servlet will take action and communicate with the webservice to update the details in DB.
Please give me some comments on the sequence diagram that I have created. Thank You.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> Disclaimer: I am the author of [ZenUML](https://www.zenuml.com). I could be biased. Some points may not be as important.

1. The length of the bar for message #3, #4, $5, #6, #7, #9, #10, #13, #16 should be extended to cover (overlap with) all child messages.
2. Lifeline1~7 is not helpful here, the class name should be enough.
3. I would add a few return arrow to present important response of some messages.

Here is a diagram (part) I reproduced with the [ZenUML Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-sequence/kcpganeflmhffnlofpdmcjklmdpbbmef?from=so).
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice. Can I know whether is it logical to put Servlet and represent it like this in sequence diagram?

Comment: UML (or sequence diagram) does not define what is a logical design. It simply represents a design. If your question is about this 'design', I personally don't think it is a good design. One obvious issue is the absence of a clearly defined layers. The relationship between WebService and GetMemberServlet is even worse. The diagram does show the problem visually (invocations in both directions).